# Re arrange data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame like

```
 col1   col2   col3   col4
  a       0     t      .1
  b       0     t      .2
  a       1     f      .3
  b       1     f      .4
```

I need to re arrange it to this format

```
         a     b
0   t   .1    .2
1   f   .3    .4
```

I know this can be done using dcast function. But I am not able figure out how exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, this can be done with `dcast` from "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, col2 + col3 ~ col1, value.var = "col4")
#   col2 col3   a   b
# 1    0    t 0.1 0.2
# 2    1    f 0.3 0.4
```

---

It can also be done with `reshape` from base R:

```
> reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar = c("col2", "col3"), timevar = "col1")
  col2 col3 col4.a col4.b
1    0    t    0.1    0.2
3    1    f    0.3    0.4
```

And with `spread`, from "tidyr":

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> mydf %>% spread(col1, col4)
  col2 col3   a   b
1    0    t 0.1 0.2
2    1    f 0.3 0.4
```

Comment: What if I have to sort all values of a and b in each row in say decreasing order?

Comment: @user3664020 - sort the values in the original data first, then reshape.